# Jenkins multi-configuration project always deleting workspace

Tags: jenkins

I have a multi-configuration project that uses Subversion SCM. To reduce the build time of my project I use the "Emulate clean" checkout strategy. However, when I inspect the output of a specific configuration, it always shows this:

```
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at c:\Jenkins\workspace\foo\Configuration\...
Cleaning local Directory .
```

So then I inspected the "root" output of the project:

```
Cleaning up c:\Jenkins\workspace\foo\.
Deleting c:\Jenkins\workspace\foo\Configuration
```

No wonder my configurations don't see an existing workspace when the root project always deletes the entire nested configuration workspace structure. Why the heck is Jenkins doing that?

Edit: How can I make Jenkins perform "Emulate clean" on the actual workspaces for the individual configurations, rather than the "root" checkout workspace?

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11993